# Permutation to arrange digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

**In how many ways can we arrange the digit 1,2,3,4,5,6 so that**

**a. 1 and 2 occurs side by side e.g 123456 or 213456 ...**

**b. 1 occurs somewhere before 2 e.g. 134562 ...**

---

**Ans**

**a.** There are 6 places, _ _ _ _ _ _

According to me we create 5 group such as 12, 3, 4, 5, 6.

According to Permutation 5P5 = **5! = 120**

This is correct?

b. Can you help me?

Comment: Note;  your solution for part a) correctly counts those permutations in which $12$ appears in that order.  But you also have to count those in which $21$ appears in that order.

Comment: Hint:  for b).  Switching the slots containing $1$ and $2$ shows that exactly half the permutations have $1$ before $2$.

Comment: @lulu : ok got it for a. its 5! + 5! = 120 + 120 = 240 correct??

Comment: It seems that half of the permutations would have 1 before 2, by symmetry.

Comment: yes, $240$ is correct.

Comment: thanx, I will try second. but need more help..

Comment: Do you see the symmetry?  Switching the location of $1$ and $2$ gives a pairing on the set of permutations...in each pair exactly one member has the $1$ before the $2$, so the number of such is exactly half the total number of permutations.

Comment: @lulu, no . Can you explain me in details? may be you can give answer if possible

Comment: I'll post something below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned the comments, the idea for b) is to argue by symmetry that exactly half the permutations have $1$ ahead of $2$.

To see this, consider the following pairing:  Given a permutation $\sigma$ we pair it with the permutation $\hat\sigma$ in which the $1$ and the $2$ are interchanged. Thus, for example, the permutation $\{3,2,5,1,6,4\}$ is paired with $\{3,1,5,2,6,4\}$.  Clearly, if in $\sigma$ we have $1$ ahead of $2$ then in $\hat\sigma$ we have $2$ ahead of $1$ and conversely.  It follows that in each such pair $[\sigma,\hat\sigma]$ we have exactly one member in which $1$ is ahead of $2$.

Note:  with $6$ letters it is somewhat tedious to write out all of the permutations, but the same argument works for smaller collections.  If, for example, we were just working with permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ then our pairs would be $$[\{1,2,3\},\{2,1,3\}]\;\;[\{1,3,2\},\{2,3,1\}]\;\;[\{3,1,2\},\{3,2,1\}]$$ And we see that exactly half have $1$ ahead of $2$.